# Weak terminal fonts in Linux (Konsole)

Tags: fonts

[image: Linux Font lacks decent sharpness]

I have a problem with font sharpness at Kubuntu 17.10. The font is not sharp enough for me as the iTerm, and I am having a hard time reading it on Linux terminals. how can I fix this? (Not talking about font names/families like Monaco, monospace, hack, source code pro etc)

I have turned on anti-aliasing, sub-pixel rendering = RGB, Hinting style = None (LCD monitor)

**edit:** *I needed something bolder sized font rendering without actually changing the font. I can't figure it out how to express it to you properly (That's why I showed it in the screenshot), the macOS renders font in a juicy way, (fonts look crisp and pretty, but in Linux distros, it lacks a bit out of the box). Easy to eye font is helpful to code with solarized colour schemes*

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have found a way to fix this.

**"Bitstream Vera Sans Mono"** font increases the sharpness of any Linux distribution (Ubuntu, Debian and all its variant, even Arch and Gentoo)

[image: Vim Font Render]

[image: Font Sharped]

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "sharpness". For me, your previous configuration was sharper!